# Entrez gene IDs from gene list using biomaRt

Tags: r, biomart

I am trying to convert a list of gene names to entrez gene IDs.

for now i have this:

```
>library(biomaRt)    
>ensembl <- useMart("ensembl", dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl")
>mapping <- getBM(attributes=c('ensembl_gene_id','ensembl_transcript_id',
                          'entrezgene', 'hgnc_symbol'),mart = ensembl)
```

This creates a table with the entrez gene IDs and names. However how can I filter out the IDs based on my gene list?

This is an example of the gene names list:
[Gene names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3byvw.png)

It is just an excel files with couple of hundred gene names in total.

Hopefully someone could help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Data

Create a vector of gene names:

```
mygenes <- c("TNF", "IL6", "IL1B", "IL10", "CRP", "TGFB1", "CXCL8")
```

#### Retrieve information from the BioMart:

```
library(biomaRt)

hsmart <- useMart(dataset = "hsapiens_gene_ensembl", biomart = "ensembl")

hsmart

# Object of class 'Mart':
#   Using the ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL BioMart database
#   Using the hsapiens_gene_ensembl dataset
```

#### Map gene names to Ensembl gene ids, transcript ids, entreze ids

To do this, you don't need to convert whole database into the table of corresponding ids. Using `filter = "hgns_symbol"` as parameter for your `getBM()` call, will subset database by gene names you've provided as a `values` argument of `getBM()` function:

```
mapping <- getBM(
  attributes = c('ensembl_gene_id', 'ensembl_transcript_id', 'entrezgene', 'hgnc_symbol'), 
  filters = 'hgnc_symbol',
  values = mygenes,
  mart = hsmart
)
```

Which give you 43 records for your genes:

```
mapping %>%
  arrange(hgnc_symbol, ensembl_gene_id, ensembl_transcript_id, entrezgene)

#   ensembl_gene_id ensembl_transcript_id entrezgene hgnc_symbol
#1  ENSG00000132693       ENST00000255030       1401         CRP
#2  ENSG00000132693       ENST00000368110       1401         CRP
#3  ENSG00000132693       ENST00000368111       1401         CRP
#4  ENSG00000132693       ENST00000368112       1401         CRP
#5  ENSG00000132693       ENST00000437342       1401         CRP
#
#   ............................................................
#
#39 ENSG00000228321       ENST00000412275       7124         TNF
#40 ENSG00000228849       ENST00000420425       7124         TNF
#41 ENSG00000228978       ENST00000445232       7124         TNF
#42 ENSG00000230108       ENST00000443707       7124         TNF
#43 ENSG00000232810       ENST00000449264       7124         TNF
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, is there a way to convert the list of gene names to a vector instead of manually typing the list?

Comment: I am not sure I understood it right, @Laurent. Do you mean, how to convert gene names from your excel file into the vector in R?

Comment: Nevermind. I set the gene names in an excel file and saved it as a .txt

I used this line to read the .txt file:
mygenes <- read.table("gene names.txt", header = T)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That what I needed to know. You can read your excel file into R using `readxl` (https://readxl.tidyverse.org/) or using `xlsx` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html) packages. The last one allows you to read (and write) separate sheets of your excel book. After that by usual subsetting (and, I am afraid unlisting in case of `readxl`) of the data, you can convert it into the vector, or directly use content of particular column with your gene names as a query for `getBM()`.

Comment: entrezgene has changed to entrezgene_id